# What causes the comand 'd.vect map' to fail in GRASS-GIS?

Tags: grass-gis

I have been having problems with visualizing my data in GRASS-GIS.

I imported my .shp file into the software following all instructions and, after that, I selected the layer I wanted to visualize.

It didn't happen at first, so I went on to the map display screen and clicked on the button that places the map within the view panel.

Unfortunately, this also did not help. I still can't see any data.

Does anybody know how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Was your import successful? Check your vector layer with v.info to see the number of features, extent etc. Did you mean the 'Zoom to selected map layer(s)' button? Which version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten to finally visualize my data. In a nutshell, I **uploaded a newer version: 6.4.4**; different from the one I was using: 6.4.3.

After doing it, I followed the same steps for importing my data and now it works.